# Error to convert latitude and longitude to location description

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, here-api

I'm developing an Android app to integrate with another app.
In this app I need get the current user location and send it to the other app.
I'm getting the latiude and longitude using the following web service:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Rua+Vergueiro,+1883,+S%C3%A3o+Paulo,+Brazil&sensor=true

The problem is that when the other app receive the latitude an longitude and convert it to address description,  an wrong address is showed to the user.

The other app is using the here.com web services to convert the latitude and longitude to address description and Im using googleapi.

Anyone knows tell me what may be happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are geocoding using one service (i.e. Google) and reverse geocoding using a second service (i.e. HERE) and the underlying data is different for each one.  As it happens, the location you are looking for is at a junction as shown [here](http://here.com/-23.5787532,-46.6395961,20,0,0,normal.day)

[image: Sao Paulo]

If you run a [reverse geocoding search](http://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox=-23.5787246,-46.6398486,150&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=5&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=3) for this location, then the **closest** location found by HERE is around the corner at *Rua Jardim Ivone* - the second closest result found by HERE is the same as Google -  *Rua Vergueiro*. As you can see from the picture this is correct - the closest house on the map to the stated location given is actually around the corner.

Comment: Hello Jason Fox, Do you know tell me how to solve this?

Comment: You have several options - 1) geocode and reverse geocode using the **same** data set (e.g. HERE to HERE). 2) Pass the `viewport` parameters from Google and a partial address and invoke area matching on HERE e.g. http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=Rua%20Vergueiro&mapview=-23.5773,-46.6384;-23.58007,-46.6411&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=4 or 3) Send the lat,lng **and** address to the other device.  Option 3) would be the simplest.

Comment: Jason Fox, I'm using the Option 3). To be more clear, I'm having the problem above by sending the latitude and longitde to the other app, 
The other app is converting my latitude/longitude in another location description. How can I implement the Option 2)?

Comment: **Option 3)** -If you are sending the full address **and** lat, lng there is no need to use the geocoder on the receiving end - just use the values you send.

Comment: **Option 2)** use the parameters in the link in the comment above i.e. `geocode.json?searchtext=[Name of Road]` `&mapview=[topLeft];[bottomRight]` `&app_id=[Your APP ID]` `&app_code=[Your App Code]`

Comment: Alternatively  retrieve mulitple addresses as shown [here](http://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox=-23.5787246,-46.6398486,150&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=5&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=3) and match on your given street address.

Comment: I'm using the option 3), but the latitude and longitude from Google API is differente of the Here API.